# Accessing data through struct one to struct two?

Tags: c, struct, linked-list, singly-linked-list

first of all I started to study Computer Science and C is the main language. I learned in my first days that you have to do a lot of "foot work" to get stuff done in C. Right now we are working with Linked Lists and got an exercise, I would like to finish. So, I would be pretty glad if some of you guys could take a look at my problem and give some tips on how to finish that problem.

If you are still reading this here is my problem:

We got 2 structs:

```
typedef struct MsgDetails {
char *id;
msgtag tag;
int year;
int month;
int day;
} MsgDetails;

typedef struct Node {
void *item;
struct Node *next;
} Node;
```

and this is the function:

```
struct Node* addMsgDetails(Node* head ,MsgDetails *MsgDetaillos) {
int tag = 0, year = 0, month = 0, day = 0;
char id;

Node *current = head;

while (current->next != NULL) {
current = current->next;
}

current->next = malloc(sizeof(Node));
current->next->next = NULL;
current->next->item = malloc(sizeof(MsgDetails));

printf("\nenter msg metadata (tag,year,month,day,id):");
scanf(" %d, %d, %d, %d, %40s", &tag, &year, &month, &day, &id);

MsgDetaillos->tag = tag;
MsgDetaillos->year = year;
MsgDetaillos->month = month;
MsgDetaillos->day = day;
MsgDetaillos->id = &id;

return current;
}
```

So the problem is that I know that I need to allocate memory for each struct when I want to add a new struct. I loop through my Node struct until I reach the Node with NULL in the next pointer. Now that I am in the right node, I also add the address of the allocated memory in the void *item pointer but now I do not know how to add the information of Msg Details struct in to the item variable. Hope that was not too confusing?

I tried to find the problem but actually also do not know how to look for it. I tried "calling data from one struct through another" and similar things but could not get an answer. I would appreciate any help, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You will assign buffer filled with data to the member of the structure instead of uninitialized buffer.
- `char` cannot hold positive-length string. You will have to allocate buffer for strings.

Instead of this

```
current->next->item = malloc(sizeof(MsgDetails));

printf("\nenter msg metadata (tag,year,month,day,id):");
scanf(" %d, %d, %d, %d, %40s", &tag, &year, &month, &day, &id);

MsgDetaillos->tag = tag;
MsgDetaillos->year = year;
MsgDetaillos->month = month;
MsgDetaillos->day = day;
MsgDetaillos->id = &id;
```

You should use this:

```
// allocate buffer for data
MsgDetails* data = malloc(sizeof(MsgDetails));
// allocate buffer for string
char* id_str = calloc(41, sizeof(char));

// check results of malloc() and calloc() here fore better safety

printf("\nenter msg metadata (tag,year,month,day,id):");
scanf(" %d, %d, %d, %d, %40s", &tag, &year, &month, &day, id_str);

// fill the buffer with data read
data->tag = tag;
data->year = year;
data->month = month;
data->day = day;
data->id = id_str;

// assign the buffer to the member of the structure
current->next->item = data;
```